# Create bluetooth RFCOMM connection without pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, rfcomm

I have a bluetooth device that collects some environmental data like temperature. I want to build an Android app that will pull the data from this device and display it. The problem here is the device is a kind of non-pairable. It simply works by writing commands on RFCOMM stream.

I just wanted to know if it is possible to create an RFCOMM connection stream without pairing the device in Android? I have tried to look at the other SO posts and blogs but didn't found any useful information.

Any help or pointing in right direction is appreciated.

Thanks